# Insert into openquery and WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I have some SQL (not written by me) and I cannot find the meaning of it.

Statement is similar to:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (linkedServerName, "SELECT col1, col2 FROM service WHERE ServiceId < 0") 
(col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Service
```

I get the point with "insert into" part, but I cannot understand the **"WHERE ServiceId < 0"** clause.

What this condition introduce to INSERT (select?) statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (linkedServerName, "SELECT col1, col2 FROM service WHERE ServiceId < 0")
```

You detail the table and columns where you want to put the data, so the WHERE makes no sense. Maybe internally it's allowed because the engine just retrieve from there the table name and the list of columns, so it doesn't return any error.

Comment: This is the way I was thinking about it. Thanks. Anyway... I will post another question connected with this query. SELECT query (on ms sql) runs in ~11sec, but insert into openquery takes ~3min. Also select from openquery is way slower than query from MySql. Where I can look for performance bootlenecks ?

Comment: I am used to use openquery against Oracle databases and the performance is always a little bit degraded compared with a natural query to the database. There are several new layers involved using openquery (network bandwidth available, you need to query the sql server to resend the query to the other server, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (linkedServerName, 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM service WHERE ServiceId < 0')
```

Above query pulls the data from the linkedserver (connected server) as per the query given in the quotes ('`SELECT col1, col2 FROM service WHERE ServiceId < 0`').

It can be correctly written as:

```
SELECT col1, col2 INTO localtable
FROM OPENQUERY (linkedServerName, 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM Service WHERE ServiceId < 0')
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have changed the direction of INSERT INTO :) I wanted to insert into MySql (linked server) from MS SQL. Not vice versa.